# Change DockPanel's already set property using style trigger

Tags: wpf, triggers, dockpanel

I want to change appearance of my dockpanel based on certain property (for e.g. tag) using style trigger. Here is my code:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="0" LastChildFill="True" 
                   Name="MyDockPanel"
                   Tag="{Binding TagForColor}"
                   Background="Blue"
                   Width="300">
            <DockPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DockPanel}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Alert">
                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Width" Value="100"/>
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="30"/>
            </DataTrigger>

                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DockPanel.Resources>
            <TextBlock Text="My Text" 
                       DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                       Name="MyText"
                       Foreground="White">
            </TextBlock>
```

Properties like Background and Width once set are not updated by trigger. I verified that the trigger is fired since size of my textblock did increase.

Could anyone tell me the reason behind this behaviour?

Thanks,
RDV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move default value of the `Background` into your `Style` as a `Setter` otherwise `Trigger` won't be able to override value which is set manually (it has higher priority). There is the same issue with `Width`. Also, not related to your problem, but instead of `DataTrigger` you can use `Trigger`

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="0" LastChildFill="True" Name="MyDockPanel" Tag="{Binding TagForColor}">
    <DockPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DockPanel}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="300"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Alert">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="30"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DockPanel.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="My Text" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="MyText" Foreground="White"/>
</DockPanel>
```

read more about [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#listing)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move Background and Width in Style.If you want to assign some default value to Background and Width properties, you should set them in setter's of style.So that whenever
 your trigger fires,the control will get values from trigger. This is the property value inheritance of wpf. Here is link:http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html#valueres.

This code should work for you:

```
 <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" LastChildFill="True" 
               Name="MyDockPanel"
               Tag="{Binding TagForColor}"

               >
    <DockPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DockPanel}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="300"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Alert">
                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Background" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Width" Value="100"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="30"/>
                </DataTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DockPanel.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="My Text" 
                   DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                   Name="MyText"
                   Foreground="White">
    </TextBlock>
</DockPanel>
```

Please let me know if this works for you.
Thanks.